# Expected view to be called with a url keyword argument named pk

Tags: django

I am using Django..

Here are my **views**

```
class SettingsValues(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = SettingsSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Settings.objects.all()
        queryset = queryset.filter(user=self.request.user.id)
        return queryset

class SettingsValuesUpdate(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Settings.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SettingsSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user.id)
```

Here is my **model**

```
class Settings(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField('auth.User', related_name='settings', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    boolean1 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    boolean2 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    boolean3 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    string1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='No description')
```

My **serializer**

```
class SettingsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Settings
        fields = ('id', 'boolean1', 'boolean2', 'boolean3', 'string1')

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'password' ,'settings', 'image')
    extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}
```

My **urls**

```
url(r'^settings/?$', views.SettingsValues.as_view()),
url(r'^updsettings/?$', views.SettingsValuesUpdate.as_view()),
```

I am using Angular 2 or postman app it does not matter.. When i return settings it is working fine. but when i try to update the user settings (PUT) it shows an error

Expected view SettingsValuesUpdate to be called with a URL keyword argument named "pk". Fix your URL conf, or set the `.lookup_field` attribute on the view correctly

Any idea ?

**EDIT**

whit the answer of vinay kumar my view is

```
class SettingsValuesUpdate(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Settings.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SettingsSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)

    @detail_route(methods='PUT')
    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user.id)
```

but there is an error still which is {"detail":"Method \"PUT\" not allowed."}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try this way.

```
from django.conf.urls import include, urls   
from rest_framework import routers

from .views import SettingsValues, SettingsValuesUpdate

router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'settings', SettingsValues, base_name='setting_values')
router.register(r'updsettings', SettingsValuesUpdate, base_name='setting_value_update')

urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Comment: where can i add this ?

Comment: it shows error TypeError: as_view() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)

Comment: `SettingValues.as_view()` and `SettingsValuesUpdate.as_view()` in the `router.register(..)`

Comment: Ok, you also need to update views.py.
pleas use viewsets.ModelViewSet instant of generics.UpdateAPIView and generics.ListAPIView

Comment: in `router.register(..)` there is not need to use `SettingValues.as_view()` just use `SettingValues` as 2nd parameter

Comment: when i try in the postman app to make a put request  in updsettings it shows     {"detail":"Method \"PUT\" not allowed."}

Comment: You may need to add `@detail_route(methods='PUT')`. as per DRF http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/ and http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views/#rewriting-our-api-using-class-based-views

Comment: this link may help you. http://www.cdrf.co/3.5/rest_framework.viewsets/ModelViewSet.html
please have a look at `modelviewset ` attribute `allowed_methods` and `http_method_names`.
if you still find deficulty then please override `dispatch()` method

Comment: hmm ok i think dispach is going to work. I an not familliar with django is there any way to suggest me what to write inside dispach?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136387/discussion-between-vinay-kumar-and-a-jk).

Answer (score 12):

In my case, I was returning a single object from `get_queryset(self)` and changing it to  `get_object(self)` fixed my problem